# How do I remove the authoring information?

Tags: nodes

I want to publish some static pages, but when I try they always show the publishing date and author, which makes them look more like a blogs.

I have looked at a way to disable the feature "authoring information" for this page, but the best I can find is how to make it anon, which is not what I want either.

The content types I have on the site are:

- Article
- Basic page
- Blog entry
- Book page
- Forum topic
- Poll

The theme I am using is Bartik 7.15, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable it for each content type, going on `admin/structure/types/manage/<content type>` (e.g. admin/structure/types/manage/article for the Article content type).

What you are looking for is in the "Display settings" tab visible at the bottom of the settings page.

[image: screenshot]