# remove "last saved" and "author" fields in from

Tags: 8, forms

How to remove "last saved" and "author" fields in from in Drupal 8? 
[image: that what i have in the end of form]

answer over here did not help [How do I remove the authoring information?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45031/how-do-i-remove-the-authoring-information)

i have tried to hide it via form_alter but no luck...

i would appreciate any help or advice... lost to much time on this already...

part of what i get in *kint($form);* if this can help:

```
→'meta' => array(10)

'#type' => string(7) "details"

'#group' => string(8) "advanced"

'#weight' => integer-10

→'#title' => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup(5)

        contents Available methods (14) 

        protected translatedMarkup -> NULL

        protected options -> array(0)

        →protected stringTranslation -> Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationManager(4)
                contents Available methods (10) 

                →protected translators -> array(2)

                    →'30' => array(1)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                    →'0' => array(1)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                →protected sortedTranslators -> array(2)

                    →Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\Translator\CustomStrings(4)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                    →Drupal\locale\LocaleTranslation(9)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                protected defaultLangcode -> string(2) "en"

                public _serviceId -> string(18) "string_translation"

        protected string -> string(6) "Status"

        protected arguments -> array(0) 

→'#attributes' => array(1)

    →'class' => array(1)

        string(19) "entity-meta__header"

'#tree' => boolTRUE

'#access' => boolTRUE

→'published' => array(4)

    '#type' => string(4) "item"

    →'#markup' => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup(5)

            contents Available methods (14) 

            protected translatedMarkup -> NULL

            protected options -> array(0)

            →protected stringTranslation -> Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationManager(4)
                    contents Available methods (10) 

                    →protected translators -> array(2)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                    →protected sortedTranslators -> array(2)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                    protected defaultLangcode -> string(2) "en"

                    public _serviceId -> string(18) "string_translation"

            protected string -> string(9) "Published"

            protected arguments -> array(0) 

    '#access' => boolFALSE

    →'#wrapper_attributes' => array(1)

        →'class' => array(1)

            string(18) "entity-meta__title"

→'changed' => array(4)

    '#type' => string(4) "item"

    →'#title' => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup(5)

            contents Available methods (14) 

            protected translatedMarkup -> NULL

            protected options -> array(0)

            →protected stringTranslation -> Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationManager(4)
                    contents Available methods (10) 

                    →protected translators -> array(2)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                    →protected sortedTranslators -> array(2)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                    protected defaultLangcode -> string(2) "en"

                    public _serviceId -> string(18) "string_translation"

            protected string -> string(10) "Last saved"

            protected arguments -> array(0) 

    →'#markup' => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup(5)

            contents Available methods (14) 

            protected translatedMarkup -> NULL

            protected options -> array(0)

            →protected stringTranslation -> Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationManager(4)
                    contents Available methods (10) 

                    →protected translators -> array(2)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                    →protected sortedTranslators -> array(2)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                    protected defaultLangcode -> string(2) "en"

                    public _serviceId -> string(18) "string_translation"

            protected string -> string(13) "Not saved yet"

            protected arguments -> array(0) 

    →'#wrapper_attributes' => array(1)

        →'class' => array(1)

            string(23) "entity-meta__last-saved"

→'author' => array(4)

    '#type' => string(4) "item"

    →'#title' => Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup(5)

            contents Available methods (14) 

            protected translatedMarkup -> NULL

            protected options -> array(0)

            →protected stringTranslation -> Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslationManager(4)
                    contents Available methods (10) 

                    →protected translators -> array(2)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                    →protected sortedTranslators -> array(2)

                        *DEPTH TOO GREAT*

                    protected defaultLangcode -> string(2) "en"

                    public _serviceId -> string(18) "string_translation"

            protected string -> string(6) "Author"

            protected arguments -> array(0) 

    '#markup' => string(5) "@dmin"

    →'#wrapper_attributes' => array(1)

        →'class' => array(1)

            string(19) "entity-meta__author"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement correctly, then you should go to your content type `Manage form display` configuration page, it should be under: `/admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE/form-display`
Then you should disable `Authored by` and/or `Authored on` by dragging them to the disabled area in the table, then click save
[image]

Comment: does not work. it is disabled and still i can see it in the form.

Answer (score 0):

The information about "last saved" and "author" is under meta in form variable.
To remove it, you need to alter form and unset these variables.

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'node_CONTENT_TYPE_form'){
    unset($form['meta']['changed']);
    unset($form['meta']['author']);
  }
}
```

Comment: interesting idea but did not work in my case.

Comment: you should clear cashe, and check if the hook is called or not !

Comment: i flush all cashes every time i make some changes to my code and hook is called because i have this:  $form['title']['#prefix'] = '<div class="my-class">';    next to what you have suggested and i get it in the form. (i have started looking to change template twig file for add/edit node, studding this option now)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
    function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'node_CONTENT_TYPE_form'){
    $form['meta']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with claro and a group content node edit form.
These did NOT work
https://www.drupal.org/project/simplify/issues/3207027
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/134540/14822 (partially worked - empty right sidebar still displayed)

what worked for me was
i. create a custom module and implement form alter like this

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter() for node form.
 */
function mymodule_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
  $roles = $current_user->getRoles();  
  if ( in_array('administrator', $roles)) {
    return;
  }
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  if ( !in_array($node->bundle(), ['mycontenttype','myothercontenttype'])) {
    return;
  }

  $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'mymodule/mymodule_simplify_node_edit';
}
```

Then create a mymodule.libraries.yml file and declared this library

```
mymodule_simplify_node_edit:
  css:
    theme:
      css/simplify.css: {}
```

This allowed me to inject css for this form. Since security is not an issue and I only wanted to simplify the form for basic user this is ok.

these are the css rules i used to fix the problem

```
.layout-region--node-secondary {
    display: none !important;
}
.layout-region--node-main .layout-region__content, .layout-region--node-footer .layout-region__content {
    max-width: 80rem !important;
}
.layout-region--node-main {
    float: none !important;
    width:  100% !important;
}
```

Comment: related: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3184667#comment-14674199